# How to scroll items -dx in RecyclerView

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

is it possible to scroll items on direction -dx when the first item is visible?

here is the [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDqJh.png)

Comment: Are you asking if you can add 300dp of extra space to the top of your recyclerview, or are you asking about overscrolling?

Comment: I am asking for extra space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these attributes to your `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>` tag:

```
android:paddingTop="300dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

This will add 300dp of vertical space to the top of your list but allow you to scroll the contents through that space.